# Solr, Tomcat and CORS

Tags: jquery, tomcat, solr, cors

I am running solr 4.3 on Apache Tomcat 9. It is deployed as a webapp and is being used by a crm product to supply indexes.

We need to perform a search of the indexes and so I am trying to question solr and am doing so using the following query:

```
http://localhost:8888/solr-intranet-int/intranet_users/suggest?q=(surname_t:*on*)
```

Works fine in my postman client so onto building a quick test page before integration. The test page is plain html hosted on its own IIS website, so on a different domain to the solr instance.

The jquery in the testpage looks like this:

```
$("#bob").autocomplete({
          source: function(request, response)
          {         
            var input = $("#bob").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "application/xml",
                url:"http://localhost:8888/solr-intranet-int/intranet_users/suggest?q=surname_t:*" + input + "*",
                success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('input.suggest-user').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');

                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            // todo
                        }));
                    },
                error: (function(data) {
                    $("#bob").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                })
            });
          },
          minLength: 3,
          open: function() {},
          close: function() {},
          focus: function(event,ui) {},
          select: function(event, ui) {}
      });
    });
```

I got the expected CORS error and so set about trying to fix these with the following in TOMCAT

```
 <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>http://localhost:5757</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Authorization</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am not sure how to proceed further. All documentation I can find relates to Jetty in solr 5 because they have moved away from tomcat, but there must be away to get the accept header, currently I get the following error in my browser:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8888/solr-intranet-int/intranet_users/suggest?q=surname_t:*jones*.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5757' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it by using a third party cors filter: I used this at the solr application level rather than at the tomcat server level:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
                <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
                <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I know the * is a bad idea for production :)

Comment: jsonp is also a way to do so as it is supported by solr out of the box (json.wrf).